# How keep aspect ratio in bitmap drawable

Tags: android

How I can keep aspect ratio if I am using gravity `fill_vertical` or `fill_horizontal`? In this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:src="@drawable/_toogle_green"
    android:gravity="bottom|fill_vertical"
/>
```

bitmap fills vertical, but in horizontal keeps original width and aspect ratio is broken.

I believe this question was asked, but I really can't find it, only for ImageView or ImageButton. But I need do that in drawables.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
<item>
     <bitmap
          android:gravity="center|bottom|clip_vertical"
          android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
</item>
```

Comment: I just wanted to fit vertical and fill horizontal keeping the aspect ratio constant and this worked perfectly for my use case. Thank you so much :)

Comment: This only works if the original image is actually bigger than the layout element.

Comment: You are right @ocramot, it doesnt scale up. For that kind of use-case you should implement a more robust and complex image scaling algorithm (if you care about image quality).

Comment: @IonutNegru do you know how to fill horizontally and crop vertically if needed, preserving aspect ratio?

Comment: @rightaway717 you can try to play with the gravity values. Reversing them should give you the desired result. Another option could be to use a wrapper ImageView (should provide more scaling options).

Comment: @IonutNegru you are quite close to what I need but my image is still stretched horizontally. I didn't find this post so I did my own, and I am really struggling after hours of digging... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809424/android-unique-splash-screen-how-to-make-it-fill-screen

Answer (score -3):

You need to set the ScaleType. See [this link to the documentation for more info.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: This is `ImageView`. I need drawable for button or other controls where impossible to use `ImageView`.