# Android unique splash screen : how to make it fill screen?

Tags: android, xml, react-native, splash-screen

I have a unique splash screen, called splash.png and sized 1280x1280, 150dpi
I use `react-native-bootsplash` in my React Native project, but I don't think it really matters.

My question is simple : how can I make my splash screen, in portrait mode, be full height, not less, ***not more***, and keep its aspect ratio so that the picture fills the screen.
Like a `background-size: cover` in css.
Or like an easy `<Image resizeMode="cover" style={{ height: '100%' }} />` in React Native.

So I have :

`android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

```xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>

    <!-- BootTheme should inherit from AppTheme -->
    <style name="BootTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <!-- set the generated bootsplash.xml drawable as activity background -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bootsplash</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

`android/app/src/main/res/drawable/bootsplash.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <item>
      <!-- your logo, centered horizontally and vertically -->
      <bitmap
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And my `splash.png` in `android/app/src/main/res/drawable/splash.png`

I tried a lot of things, a lot of combinations of [`android:layout_height`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout), [`android:scaleType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType) and all, and I always end-up with a splash image's height overflowing the screen height.

[EDIT]
Here is the splash original image, with the size reduced enough to have a small size for stackoverflow

[image: splash original image]

and here is what it give on screen...

[image: stretched screen image]

Comment: can you post a picture of your splash screen?

Comment: try adding     android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: for `item` or `bitmap` ?

Comment: can you try `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: for `item` or `bitmap` ?

Answer (score 8):

I think the key here is `android:gravity="fill"`.

I had the same issue when I was implementing it in my application.

My `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
 <style name="BootTheme" parent="AppTheme">
<!-- set bootsplash.xml as background -->
<item name="android:background">@drawable/bootsplash</item>
```

and my `android/app/src/main/res/drawable/bootsplash.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@mipmap/launch_screen" android:gravity="fill" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: mm it's not working for me, the height is correct but the width's image is stretched to fill the screen's width...

Comment: gravity fill stretch the image in both side

Answer (score 4):

for center image with background image fillup..
step1: create a Drawable resource file inside drawable in res
step2: paste the code below replacing with background images as your image and logo

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/backgroundmapsneww"
    android:gravity="fill"
    />
<item
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawable="@drawable/logo"
    >
</item>
```

Comment: no it didn't work, the background image is still stretched

Comment: what is the size of your background image

Comment: it is 1280x1280

Comment: so you are using an square image and expecting it to not stretch .. i think using an larger image but in rectangular shape might be an option using the above code

Answer (score 3):

Splash screen implemented as a launcher theme is mostly meant for showing logos and not full images. You can try to nine-patch the image for different resolutions, use this website:

http://ticons.fokkezb.nl/

Upload your image (use 3:4 aspect ratio, e.g. 1080x1920, for the best results) and select -> splashes. It will generate nine-patch images for you, which you then need to upload to your `res/drawable-hdpi`, `res/drawalbe-mdpi`, `res/drawable-xhdpi`, `res/drawable-xxhdpi` and `res/drawable-xxxhdpi` directories. If they do not exist yet, you can just create them.

Use it like this after uploading nine-patched images:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:gravity="fill" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

I was able to achieve reasonable results using the image you provided. Let me know, if this has helped. This is the best you can get. Other option would be to create your own `SplashActivity` which would show that image for you for a short period of time.

Comment: Yes I finally did that. It means to me that there is no way to setup a full screen splash screen with only one image in Android, whereas on iOS is straight forward. Too bad !

Comment: Since Android is supporting so many different screen sizes, thats for sure not straight forward. As you can also see, the big tech companies like Facebook or AirBnb are just using some simple logo + text in splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

The approach with Bitmap did not seem to succeed. Are you happy with an alternative?

What about using a layout for your SplashActivity/-Fragment like the following?

Pretty useful to display additional information like Appversion, Support's contact, Progress etc. - that's why I personally prefer it.

Done in Kotlin working with ViewModels, you might probably know it better for ReactNative.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_splash"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see `centerCrop` is key. It will cut the image, but retain its aspect ratio.

Now inflate the layout in SplashActivity, where you could also let the user sign in or so, then display the result in the layout and when done, switch to MainActivity.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
    }
```

...or Fragment

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(Application())
            .create(viewModel::class.java)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash, container, false)
    }
```

**Alternative Solution**

Using this as a layout, if you don't plan to display anything more than just the image itself in the future.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash"/>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: you seem to know quite well your subject ! so may I ask : I tried your Alternative Solution, but it seems that using a ImageView or anything with capital letters in the `drawable/bootsplash.xml` makes the app crashes at start, do you know why ?

Comment: the crash is due to: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable drawable/splash with resource ID #0x7f07005e`

Comment: your first approach didn't build: `AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf (aka com.application:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf) not found.`

Comment: @arnaudambro If you want to use a ConstrainLayout you also need to add the dependency for it: implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-rc1' Also make sure the drawables you use are named correctly. Resources should be named with lowercase letters. Additionally you might want it to start with things like ic_ if they are an icon or bt_ if it's a button. Finally please accept this answer if it solved your issue :)

Answer (score -1):

I have done this by using `FrameLayout` and `ImageView`. Write down below code in your `android/app/src/main/res/drawable/bootsplash.xml`:

```xml
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
>
  <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:src="@drawable/splash" 
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
  />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: if I put this the app doesn't even start, it crashes